# Are achievements still available while playing on a prior version on the game?

Tags: steam, achievements, europa-universalis-iv

**Can I continue an (old) Ironman game on a prior version and earn achievements ?**

I was trying a World Conquest with Ottomans and a new patch has been released recently.

Comment: I don't know what the answer is for EUIV, but I know for CKII it's “no” by direct experience.

Comment: My guess would be - yes, you can. Achievements are triggered client side, and if only this given achievement was available in the previous patch you should be fine. But don't take my word for it, you may waste your time doing this as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.  Or, at least, you could add of the last version.  Not played since, been addicted to Kerbal.

Comment: Yes, you can, I just got 2 of them this weekend while playing with only Cossacs